# Issues with Apache and Centos. Crashes at startup but cannot find startup script. apigility

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, php7, zend-framework

I inherited a Centos 7 server which has apigility installed.
When I rebooted the server, the web service crashes.
In the log files all I see is

[core:notice] [pid 3864] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3864] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

If I then run '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND' as root the apache service starts.

There are a few issues. There is no /etc/init.d/apache2 file or similar.
There is no "apache" service or similar.

I cannot find the startup script which invokes the apache service in the first place!

The log files are under /etc/httpd/logs
. So I tried editing the /etc/httpd/conf/ files to enable debug logging but I do not see more data in the log files.

I need to figure out what invokes httpd when the server boots, and why it crashes... any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: The service name is 'httpd', not apache.  This has been standard on CentOS / RHEL as long as I can remember.  On CentOS 7, the systemd unit file should be at /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service if it's active, not in /etc/init.d/ as CentOS 7 uses SystemD.  If it isn't there, check /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service (which is what the first one should be symlinked to when enabled).

Comment: Thanks I found the file under  /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service

Comment: Thanks I found the file under  /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
Also, thanks to your tip I realized that in centos the command "systemctl status httpd.service" is very usefull... the service for some reason was dissabled.  But if that is the case, why did I get a crash log when the server boots?

Comment: @yoonix the error message I was seeing is from when the server was shutting down.. not booting up! Please convert your comment into an answer in order to accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoonix deserves this answer but he never returned to claim it:
Found the file under /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service 
Thanks to your tip I realized that in centos the command "systemctl status httpd.service" is very usefull... the service for some reason was dissabled.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.  I gave an incomplete answer and you connected the dots.